# Making a volleyball game, overlap not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, overlap

I'm making a 2D game on Unity and I created an overlap to see if the ball is on the hit area. However, whenever I push the hit button, the ball is hit even if it is away of the player. I am sending the code for the Player, which contains what is needed so far, to see what may have gone wrong. Supposedly with the foreach hitCollider in hitColliders it should be fixed but it is not working I and just can´t wrap my mind around it.

```
public int speed;
public bool estoyFloor, subiendo, bajando;
public bool canRight, canLeft;
public bool canMove;

public float posYinit;
public Vector3 posInitPlayer;
bool m_Started;
public LayerMask m_LayerMask;
public GameObject volleyBall;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    m_Started = true;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{

    Collider2D[] hitColliders = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll(gameObject.transform.position, transform.localScale / 2, 0);


    foreach (Collider2D hitCollider in hitColliders)
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            volleyBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
            volleyBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector3(300, 500));
        }
    }
}

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    if (m_Started)
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, transform.localScale / 2);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        canMove = true;

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0 && canRight)
        transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0 && canLeft)
        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && estoyFloor)
    {
        subiendo = true;
        posYinit = transform.position.y;
    }

    if (transform.position.y > posYinit + 2.5f)
    {
        subiendo = false;
        bajando = true;
    }

    if (!estoyFloor && !subiendo)
        bajando = true;

    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + new Vector3(0, -1, 0), Color.red);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + new Vector3(0.8f, 0, 0), Color.red);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 0), Color.red);

    RaycastHit2D[] hitDown = Physics2D.LinecastAll(transform.position, transform.position + new Vector3(0, -1, 0));
    RaycastHit2D[] hitsRight = Physics2D.LinecastAll(transform.position, transform.position + new Vector3(0.8f, 0, 0));
    RaycastHit2D[] hitsLeft = Physics2D.LinecastAll(transform.position, transform.position + new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 0));

    estoyFloor = false;
    foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in hitDown)
    {
        if (hit.collider.name == "Floor")
        {
            bajando = false;
            estoyFloor = true;
        }
    }

    canRight = true;
    foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in hitsRight)
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Wall")
            canRight = false;
    }

    canLeft = true;
    foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in hitsLeft)
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Wall")
            canLeft = false;
    }

    if (subiendo)
        transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (bajando)
        transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: You check if there are colliders in your hitbox. Then you hit the ball as many times as the number of colliders in your hitbox. You never check what is in your hitbox, and you don't push the gameobject(s) that is in the hitbox (but push the ball no matter what).

Answer (score 0):

Your overlap box is probably colliding with the player it is on. Because you do not check if the collider belonged to the volleyball in your loop, you are hitting the ball no matter what. Try to get the transform from the collider and check its tag to see if it is a volleyball before adding force to the ball and see if that works. You could also use a layermask on your Overlap box check as well to ensure only volleyballs get detected.